# Powershell doesn't show result exactly (ip address)

Tags: powershell, select-string

i try to get just `1.1.2.1` but it shows me other `ip` too

my test code is

```
$reader = @([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("c:\test2.log")) |select-string "1.1.2.1"

$reader = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("c:\test2.log") |select-string "1.1.2.1"

$reader = get-content c:\test2.log |select-string "1.1.2.1"
```

and

- test2.log

  ```
  10.1.101.1  test101

  10.1.102.1  test102

  121.132.252.1   test104

  100.101.122.1   test105

  1.1.1.1 test1

  1.1.2.1 test2
  ```
- result

  ```
  10.1.102.1    test102

  100.101.122.1    test105

  1.1.2.1    test2
  ```

i don't know why it shows me `test102,test105`

please anyone tell me how to fix this

i tried this in `Powershell v2,v3`

---

sorry i forgot to explan a part of original code

{$pinghostname = Get-Content $HOSTS |Select-String -Pattern "$ip" | %{($_ -split "`t`t")[1]}

"1.1.2.1" should be a $ip

it means i can't use regexp

Comment: it solved with Select-String -SimpleMatch option

Answer (score 0):

```
get-content test2.log | Select-String "1\.1\.2\.1"
```

works, as does

```
$ip="1\.1\.2\.1"
get-content test2.log | Select-String $ip
```

Comment: {$pinghostname = Get-Content $HOSTS |Select-String -Pattern "$ip" | %{($_ -split "tt")[1]}

"1.1.2.1" should be a $ip

it means i can't use regexp